# HTML/CSS - Left Align and center on same line

Tags: html, css, text-align

I want to left align some text and center another Text on the same line in HTML and CSS. I also want a `margin-left` on the left-aligned text.

This is my current approach:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1 class="align-left">LEFT</h1>
  <h1>CENTER</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.align-left {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
```

This works with left and right align, but the margin also pushes the centered text. I think this is because the `float: left` keeps the left-aligned text in the page flow.

Thank you really much :)

Comment: display:inline-block;

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I think you could use `line-height:0;` in css to make two lines appear as if on one line. One line could be alligned to the left, the other could be centered. See; http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWayPB You don't need absolute positioning for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use like this

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1 class="align-left">LEFT</h1>
  <h1 class="align-center">CENTER</h1>
</div>
<style>
h1.align-left {
    text-align:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:absolute;
}

h1.align-center{
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Other way:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1 class="align-left">LEFT</h1>
  <h1 class="align-center">CENTER</h1>
</div>
<style>
h1.align-left{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:absolute;
}
#wrapper {
    text-align:left;
}

h1.align-center{
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Comment: It's also possible to add the `text-align: center;` to the wrapper, right? Since I want more text to be centered as well.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but you have to give position:absolute,margin,padding to left heading. then it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to adjust the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1><span class="align-left">LEFT</span>CENTER</h1>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/zt0mjh1u/)**

If you do not want the center text adjusting as the left text gets longer, use positioning CSS (with the same HTML I've posted).

```
.align-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
}

#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo for positioning**](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/zt0mjh1u/1/)

Be aware... if you don't want the center text to adjust, it **is** possible that the text is going to overlap.

Comment: When you add more text to the *LEFT*, the centered Element is pushed to the left as well.

Comment: This works, but I'm a little bit confused, why it does. The `position: absolute;` is takes the `.align-left` out of the flow and positions it `20px` to the right of it normal position, right? I would think, that the normal position is centered as well (since, it is contained in the wrapper). Also: Why do I need the `position: relative;` for the wrapper?

Comment: `position: absolute;` **starts** at 0,0 or top, left corner. Then any values are added/subtracted from that position. By adding `position: relative` to the **parent** selector, you tell the absolute positioning to start at 0,0 of the *parent element* rather than the window. So.. in this case setting `position: absolute;` on the "left" text tells it to start at the left side of `#wrapper`.. then adding `left: 20px;` moves in from the left side, the same way your margin was moving it inward. Alternatively, I could have added `h1 {position: relative;}` to tell "left" to start at 0,0 of the h1.

Answer (score 2):

My two cents.

CSS code:

```
h1{
  display: inline-block;
}
#center{
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1 id="left">LEFT</h1>
  <h1 id="center">CENTER</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it with the code below. The order of the articles tags won't matter, the css takes care to position them correctly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            section {
                border: 1px solid #ff0000;
                overflow: hidden;
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
            }
            section article.txt {
                border: 1px solid green;
                max-width: 35%;
            }
            section article.left { float: left; }
            section article.right { float: right; }
            
            section article.center {
                --width: 300px;
                position: absolute;
                margin: 0 50%;
                left: calc((var(--width) / 2) - var(--width));
                width: var(--width);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <article class="txt left">Text LEFT side</article>
            <article class="txt right">Text RIGHT side</article>
            <article class="txt center">Text CENTER</article>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```